# Pentaho can't connect to sql server (Native)

Tags: jdbc, pentaho-data-integration

I am using Pentaho Data Integration (9.1) and trying to connect to my SQL Server  Database using windows Authentification but when I do, I get an error.

Knowing that I can get access to my database using SQL Management Studio and during last month my PDI works perfectly with authentification windows.

Message error:

Connection failed. Verify all connection parameters and confirm that the appropriate driver is installed.
Read timed out ClientConnectionId:689b127e-eda6-4240-9e30-766e491ab776

here the log error :

```
    Connection failed. Verify all connection parameters and confirm that the appropriate driver is installed.
    Read timed out ClientConnectionId:21a446a1-3fa6-4050-8687-4311c614cd1a

            at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:493)
            at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:389)
            at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:360)
            at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:350)
            at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:85)
            at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestResults(DatabaseFactory.java:115)
            at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnectionSuccess(DatabaseMeta.java:2848)
            at org.pentaho.ui.database.event.DataHandler.testDatabaseConnection(DataHandler.java:649)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:313)
            at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:157)
            at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:141)
            at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton.access$500(SwtButton.java:43)
            at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton$4.widgetSelected(SwtButton.java:137)
            at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:820)
            at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:796)
            at org.pentaho.di.ui.xul.KettleDialog.show(KettleDialog.java:89)
            at org.pentaho.di.ui.xul.KettleDialog.show(KettleDialog.java:56)
            at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.XulDatabaseDialog.open(XulDatabaseDialog.java:126)
            at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.DatabaseDialog.open(DatabaseDialog.java:61)
            at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.step.BaseStepDialog.showDbDialogUnlessCancelledOrValid(BaseStepDialog.java:818)
            at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.step.BaseStepDialog$EditConnectionListener.widgetSelected(BaseStepDialog.java:1526)
            at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
            at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInputDialog.open(TableInputDialog.java:463)
            at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonStepsDelegate.editStep(SpoonStepsDelegate.java:120)
            at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.editStep(Spoon.java:8854)
            at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph.editStep(TransGraph.java:3287)
            at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph.mouseDoubleClick(TransGraph.java:785)
            at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
            at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1405)
            at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7989)
            at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9371)
            at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:711)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
    Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
    Connection failed. Verify all connection parameters and confirm that the appropriate driver is installed.
    Read timed out ClientConnectionId:21a446a1-3fa6-4050-8687-4311c614cd1a

            at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:601)
            at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:477)
            ... 56 more
    Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Read timed out ClientConnectionId:21a446a1-3fa6-4050-8687-4311c614cd1a
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:3151)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.read(IOBuffer.java:2060)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.Prelogin(SQLServerConnection.java:2862)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2704)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2362)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2213)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1276)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:861)
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
            at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:585)
            ... 57 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
            at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
            at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
            at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
            at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.read(IOBuffer.java:2054)
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server, which version of Java, which version of the SQL Server JDBC driver, and what is your connection string?

Comment: Sql server version : Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU10) (KB5001090) - 15.0.4123.1 (X64)   Mar 22 2021 18:10:24   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard  
java version :"1.8.0_281" 
JDBC DRIVER: mssql-jdbc_auth-8.4.1.x86.dll my connection string use Windows authentification I have set the name of the server and database name port number to : 1433 and checked use Integrated Security

Comment: Please edit your question, don't add information in comments. And `mssql-jdbc_auth-8.4.1.x86.dll` is not your JDBC driver, it is a helper library of the JDBC driver.